# Pass generic string value as function parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

I am writing a database abstraction layer in TypeScript, which shall allow me to select from a main table (e.g. users) with another table joined (e.g. comments). I'm trying to get the typings correct, using intersection types like `A & B`.

I am currently stuck with something similar to this:

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface Comment {
  id: number;
  user_id: number;
  comment: string;
}

class QueryBuilder<Type> {
  async exec(): Promise<Type[]> {
    return [];
  }

  join<SubType, MapType extends string>(mapField: MapType):
    QueryBuilder<Type & {[key in typeof mapField]: SubType[]}> {
      return new QueryBuilder<Type & {[key in typeof mapField]: SubType[]}>();
    }
}

// I have to specify 'comments' twice below, one for the generic and one for the function param
(new QueryBuilder<User>()).join<Comment, 'comments'>('comments').exec().then(users => {
  for (const user of users) {
    for (const comment of user.comments) {
      console.log(`comment of user ${user.id}: ${comment.comment}`);
    }
  }
});
```

You can check out the example on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANz7lxURnphSgDmjAvrlyhIsRCgDCAeyqtwOJsTKVaDJhUxQA%20ovLU6URgQTTZYdpx79BCADZx06ZAEUK0AJ4AhCsBtFoAHgAVNwAHCAA%20eQJ7NxAEZAgADwgEAAoASjIABShpYEwg0IgAbQBdSLwCAigIMAooEGQyw2QBJgArSVB-AGUKGmCwgBpkAFk4EMGUJMgQIkcOLhBucNSqCYAxYAhfMnHJosymAhd3Lx8-KEKw5AAyHGKAawg3QkawIskYZHWQrZ2iKUyH0BkUynwKscqjU6g1yBAAO7OVxQTzeXwBKZ3B7PV6gZAfMJfH6bba%20IHIEFTcGrdItAgCNoAeiZyAAksgABZwABuKDAkmQ6DCCGAMFeAHJjDIIOB0BKCQjgEhkHQbJIESNJCAUDBJFACZyUNxZdBlcg4HNkNrdfrDbqKHEwMBtcgQnAoCxcKkdUjTqjzhirhhoLT0gA6TrdKQy8AjKUmWVgeWrBOx5MSiNJFIZcNgI0gVLqaCOAC8kIIeoNqWMIA4yGLBuJjfQ6SiVSryBr2vr0tM1u%20jfDfaTrfbVWQtfQkhsEHD6u4qQABiO5M2NMgACTYIfEPhkbersDDxPgPhLulQgQM3B8S9AA).

How can I change the definition of my `join` method so I don't have to mention the map type twice? It's important to have the actual value for the return type definition (in this example, a field 'comments' is added to the current type object) as well as a function parameter, so the actual JavaScript code can add that additional property to the object.

Comment: What is `map` in your code? `async` cannot appear in an interface. Please correct your example.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WzOd1w) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Thanks catgirlkelly and @jcalz, I corrected my example accordingly and added a link to a working playground example.

Comment: So you want *partial type parameter inference* as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) but it doesn't exist.  All you can do is work around it, such as making `join()` a *curried* method like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Ndog6w).  See the linked questions and answers for more information.